# Rational synergy: Cannot login with username

Tags: linux, cm-synergy

I'm working on a Linux system (Debian Stretch, x86_64) and try to login to rational synergy, but the id shown in the textfield "User-ID" is "unknown" and the text field is disabled. The client log put out a warning:

```
Warning: Cannot start Synergy as user <my-user-id>.
Using the current user (unknown) instead.
```

I have set `user.default.id` in my `.ccm.user.properties` file. My user-id is an ldap-id.

If I start `cmsynergy` as root the client warning looks like this

```
Warning: Cannot start Synergy as user <my-user-id>.
Using the current user (root) instead.
```

and the field "User-ID" is set to "root".
On Linux the command `cmsynergy` doesn't support the `-n` parameter to change the username. So there is no possibility to login with my username. How can I fix this problem?

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the Problem by installing the libnss-sss library for i386.

```
    aptitude install libnss-sss:i386
```